# How to connect to a Windows PC through SSH from an Android phone?

Tags: windows, ssh

I have **connectbot** in my Android Phone (GT-N7000). How can I access a PC through that app ? I tried to use **putty** to establish ssh in my PC but it didn't work well. Can anyone give my a solution to this problem?

Comment: You didn't really provide enough information to enable us giving good answers: what OS is running on your PC? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 x86

Comment: OK, that's already one point (I've added the corresponding tag to your question). Still lacking: What are you trying to achieve? Windows doesn't run an SSH server by default, so you won't have much luck with ConnectBot here without taking care for a counter-part on your PC. Maybe a [different solution](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=148) is more suitable?

Comment: Glad to read I was able to help! So maybe I should make that an answer with some more details?

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's some trouble in your conception: [Connectbot](http://www.appbrain.com/app/connectbot/org.connectbot) is an SSH client, while Windows does not ship with an SSH server pre-installed. So unless you've installed some SSH server there yourself (details on that part are beyond the scope of this site), you won't have much luck connecting.

You didn't exactly write what you want to achieve, but there are [different solution](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=148) to connect your Android device to control your PC. As shipped, Windows supports the [Remote Desktop Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) (aka RDP), for which several Android clients exist. The page behind [this link](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=148) lists up some of them. Other than with Connectbot, this will be in graphical mode, not command-line.

A general solution (valid for other OSes as well) could also be using [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC). Again, this would require a server software to be installed on your PC, a corresponding client app on your Android device (also to be found on the mentioned list), and it would be in graphical mode.

Comment: WSL brings OpenSSH to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use [TeamViewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile)

Easy to setup if you want a quick working solution. Plus it works with Mac/Windows/Linux.